# Elasticsearch retrieve ZonedDateTime - failed to map source [{}] to class

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data, zoneddatetime

I am using spring-data Elasticsearch repository to store data and retrieve data from Elasticsearch using the high level rest client. The field being stored is of type ZonedDateTime, and although it is successfully storing the value, its erroring on mapping it back to the data class.

This error is thrown when I attempt to retrieve the document by id:

```
org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: failed to map source [ {"time":"2020-04-20T14:01:38.470305Z"}] to class TimeTest] with root cause
```

The field in the timeTest data class (holds the field), and the Test class it extends (holds the id):

```
@Document(indexName = "test")
public class TimeTest extends Test{

  @Field(type = FieldType.Date)
  private ZonedDateTime time;

  \\getters and setters
}


@Document(indexName = "test")
public abstract class Test {

  @Id
  private String id;

  \\getters and setters
}
```

The customEntityConfiguration so that Jackson recognises Java Date & Time API

```
 @Bean
  ElasticsearchRestTemplate elasticsearchTemplate(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    return new ElasticsearchRestTemplate(client(), new CustomEntityMapper(objectMapper));
  }

  public class CustomEntityMapper implements EntityMapper {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public CustomEntityMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
      this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
      objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
      objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
      objectMapper.registerModule(new CustomGeoModule());
      objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    }

    @Override
    public String mapToString(final Object object) throws IOException {
      return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T mapToObject(final String source, final Class<T> clazz) throws IOException {
      return objectMapper.readValue(source, clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> mapObject(Object source) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return null;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T readObject(Map<String, Object> source, Class<T> targetType) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return null;
    }

  }
```

The methods to save (which works) and retrieve by id (which errors):

```
  @Override
  public void store(ZonedDateTime time) {
    repository.save(time);
  }

  @Override
  public TimeTest getResult(String id) {
    return repository.findById(id);
  }
```

The field is being stored correctly, as seen from the Json response from curl localhost:9200/test/_doc/12345?pretty

```
{
  "_index" : "test",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "12345",
  "_version" : 1,
  "_seq_no" : 0,
  "_primary_term" : 2,
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "time" : "2020-04-20T14:01:38.470305Z"
  }
}
```